# Stack overflow internacionales: ilimitado, a tiempo y completo en su idioma nativo

Tags: discusión, sitios-internacionales

Enlace al original: [International Stack Overflows: Unlimited, On Time, and Comprehensive in your native language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/141717)

> #### TL; DR
>
> La gente ha preguntado: "¿Cuál es la misión de nuestros sitios internacionales? ¿Qué problemas solucionan?" La respuesta "son como Stack Overflow en inglés, solo en un idioma diferente" hace que los sitios internacionales sean aún más misteriosos. Pensamos que sería genial disipar la niebla del misterio al agregar un artículo del centro de ayuda sobre la misión de estos sitios internacionales. Por favor, echa un vistazo a **https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto** y dinos lo que piensas. Es editable por los moderadores y agradeceríamos las traducciones.

Por favor, déjame darte algunos pensamientos detrás de esta misión. Para comenzar, piensa en la diferencia entre un desarrollador nativo de habla inglesa y un desarrollador no nativo de habla inglesa. ¿Cómo afecta esta diferencia a sus vidas?

[image]
<sub>(Encontre esta imagen en [Google Images](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/styles/the_breaking_news_image_style/public/nick-shepherd-illustration-040216.jpg).)</sub>

#### El problema de los desarrolladores que no hablan inglés: menos, tarde y pobre.

Si buscas una respuesta de programación en un idioma que no sea el inglés, en su mayoría encontrarás enlaces a foros abrumadores similares a phpBB, respuestas dispersas en comentarios de blogs personales, cadenas de listas de correo de desarrolladores, etc. La única fuente de información de calidad en ese idioma sigue siendo los libros. Parece que todavía estamos estancados en 2007...

Como resultado, existe una tremenda asimetría en la información disponible en diferentes idiomas. Los desarrolladores de todo el mundo que no hablan inglés tienen *menos* información disponible, aparece *tarde*, y algunos matices importantes se *pierden*.

¿Ha impactado Stack Overflow en inglés a los desarrolladores que no hablan inglés? ¡Sí, por supuesto! En los últimos años, hemos visto el [amanecer de sitios con contenido de Stack overflow traducido automáticamente](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6). Uno solo puede soñar que ha sido una traducción automática de calidad con correcciones humanas, pero es un montón de contenido similar al spam, que en la mayoría de los casos no tiene ningún sentido para un ser humano. Hay una docena de sitios de este tipo con algunos millones de páginas generadas en cada uno. Esto es lo que nosotros, desarrolladores que no hablan inglés, vemos en los resultados de búsqueda cada día... y no es una broma.

La situación crea una gran desigualdad entre los desarrolladores cuyo primer idioma es el inglés y el resto de nosotros. Para una gran parte de la población mundial, la programación en sí misma es una gran área gris, el umbral para ingresar a la industria sigue siendo alto, el aprendizaje de la programación es muy difícil y costoso.

Actualmente, la TI no está bien diseñada para personas fuera del mundo de habla inglesa. ¡Pero, juntos vamos a cambiar esa tendencia!

#### El objetivo: respuestas detalladas a cualquier pregunta de programación posible en su idioma nativo.

En nuestro mundo actual, dos personas con habilidades similares y pasión por la programación comienzan a aprender al mismo tiempo. Unos años más tarde, ambos irán al aeropuerto para asistir a una conferencia en el mismo taxi. Sin embargo, una de las personas (el hablante nativo de inglés) será un presentador en la conferencia, mientras que el otro (el hablante no inglés) será el conductor del taxi. Nuestra misión y objetivo final para los sitios Stack Overflow internacionales es crear un mundo donde todos tengan las mismas oportunidades de tener éxito en la programación, independientemente de su idioma nativo o cualquier otro prejuicio.

Nuestro deseo es tener más autos autocontrolados y menos desarrolladores-conductores en todo el mundo.

#### Solución de Stack Overflow: ilimitada, a tiempo y completa.

Todos comienzan igual, con una fuerte pasión por ser un desarrollador. La única diferencia es que algunos de nosotros tenemos *suficiente material completo* cuando es necesario en su idioma nativo. Otros no lo tienen. Nosotros, los que no lo tenemos, tenemos que gastar millones de horas adicionales solo en traducir, revisar y revisar el contenido muchas veces mientras aclaramos todos los matices de una tecnología. Si queremos ser efectivos, necesitamos cambiar esta tendencia. Creemos que un buen punto de partida es la creación de una biblioteca bien estructurada de respuestas detalladas a todas las preguntas de programación y una comunidad de ayuda mutua.

#### Stack Overflow habla muchos idiomas

Stack Overflow es sobre nosotros. Se trata de todos los desarrolladores de todo el mundo que desean ayudar a otros y que buscan una respuesta en línea, independientemente de los límites del idioma, ya sea de programación o humano.

Para hacer que el tesoro de la sabiduría comunitaria esté disponible para todos, ¡necesitamos tenerte a bordo! Únete a nuestros sitios internacionales, haz y responde preguntas y comparte los sitios con tus amigos. Diles por qué existen los sitios Stack Overflow internacionales y cuál es su misión. Tu recomendación es la única manera en que los sitios internacionales crecerán.

Comment: El "manifesto" de Stack Overflow en español está en ... redoble de tambor ... **inglés**.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos cuando tenes razon tenes razon.. necesitamos a un mod para esto...

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos estábamos en proceso de aceptar una traducción. Ya está traducido :)

Answer (score 10):

*Lo siguiente es la traducción del [manifiesto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto). Podéis editarla si veis algo que podamos mejorar, y una vez nos parezca bien algún moderador debe editar el manifiesto*

---

**Actualizacion**

*El [manifiesto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) ya ha sido traducido. Si tenéis alguna nueva sugerencia, añadid una respuesta a esta pregunta para someterla a votación*

---

### Manifiesto de Stack Overflow en español

## Misión

Con tu ayuda, queremos crear una recopilación de respuestas detalladas y útiles para cualquier pregunta que pueda surgir en el mundo del desarrollo del software.

## El problema con el conocimiento en español: Menos - Tardío - Pobre.

- Tenemos *menos* documentación en español sobre tecnología.
- El conocimiento aparece con un *retraso*.
- Lo que está disponible tiende a *no ser exacto o claro*.

## Solución: Ilimitado - A tiempo - Completo.

- *Conocimiento ilimitado* a partir de respuestas de personas reales a preguntas sobre desarrollo de software.
- Los compañeros desarrolladores te ayudan con el conocimiento *a tiempo*, cuando lo necesitas.
- Detalles *completos* relacionados con una solución en una respuesta. En ella, el autor explica, en sus propias palabras, cómo ha resuelto el mismo problema.

## Objetivo

Crear un mundo en el que, para cualquier consulta a un motor de búsqueda, los resultados de la búsqueda muestren el enlace a una respuesta detallada en español.

## ¿Cómo llegamos allí? Desarrollador a desarrollador - con respeto.

- Los usuarios moderan el contenido del sitio y lideran la comunidad con el ejemplo.
- Los usuarios enseñan a sus colegas y aprenden de ellos de forma gratuita. El resultado de la interacción, la base de conocimientos de programación, [se comparte con toda la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3695).
- Los usuarios apoyan la atmósfera de aprendizaje, seguridad y respeto mutuo en el sitio.

## Eres parte de Stack Overflow en español. Sin ti, no funcionará.

¡Creemos en las personas, en la comunidad y en ti! [Únete](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/signup) a la comunidad, [haz preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) y [responde](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) las preguntas de otros y [administra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) el contenido del sitio. ¡Comparte el sitio y su misión con tus compañeros! Sin ti y tu ayuda, no podremos mejorar.

Realiza un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por el sitio para descubrir cómo funciona Stack Overflow en español.

---

Pensamientos detrás de esta misión: [Stack overflow internacionales: Ilimitado, a tiempo y completo en su idioma nativo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3693)

---

**IMPORTANTE**

Esta traducción está abierta a edición en caso de detectarse algún fallo ortografico, gramatical... Si alguien quiere proponer algún cambio más profundo que afecte al sentido del texto, la mejor forma de hacerlo es crear una respuesta con la sugerencia en cuestión, y que así pueda ser votada y debatida.

Comment: A mi personalmente me parece mejor la redacción original de la misión que la edición de @kennybarrera. Harían falta mas opiniones al respecto

Comment: A mi no me convence lo de "Obtener la mejor respuesta" ya que es algo bastante subjetivo y además en ocasiones hay varias respuestas que se complementan y no una única respuesta. A veces la mejor respuesta para el OP no es la mejor para la comunidad y viceversa pero aún así pueden ser útiles todas. Yo lo dejaría como estaba

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que las modificaciones en esta publicación deben limitarse a hacer una traducción del original en inglés, pero con responde a cambios profundos, no me queda claro si esto se puede determinar por la comunidad SOes sin incluir a las otras comunidades SO internacionales.

Comment: Podemos publicar esto??? Jose tiene razon!

Comment: Hello everyone! Many thanks for translating the manifesto. I've added the translation to the help center. Could you please check [it](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky I've just edited 2 small things extracted from the answer by Pablo Lozano as it has +7 votes. Could you change it in the help center?

Comment: @Pikoh Hi! Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the help center article.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky i think it's ok now. If there is any suggestion to change it, we'd let you know. Thank you :)

Comment: @Pikoh Thank you! By the way, I've created [a chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317209/) where you can ping me if I can help you somehow. Please do!

Answer (score 6):

### Propuesta para el párrafo referente a la **misión**

Con tu ayuda, queremos crear una recopilación de respuestas detalladas y útiles para cualquier pregunta que pueda surgir en el mundo del desarrollo del *software*.

### Propuesta para el problema **menos**

Tenemos *menos* documentación en español sobre tecnología.

(Porque menos conocimiento suena a que los desarrolladores conocen menos o somos menos capaces)

Comment: Sugiero cambiar "una recopilación" con "un acervo"

Comment: aca en argentina no se entiende que es un acervo. @Barranka

Comment: Tampoco se usa apenas en España, aunque sería totalmente correcto.

Comment: @gbianchi: En el [diccionario](http://www.aal.edu.ar/node/198) incluido en el sitio web de la Academia Argentina de Letras aparece la la palabra `acervo` :) Cabe destacar que se trata del diccionario de la RAE.

Comment: si pero olvidate que se entienda... @Rubén

Comment: ¿Qué tal `colección` o `conjunto`?

Comment: si si.. puede ser.. pero la idea es que el usuario comun y corriente no tenga que ir a un diccionario!!! bah, me parece.. igual no es un termino incorrecto... pero creo que si le digo a mi hijo que revise el texto me va a preguntar que es un acervo.. ;)

Comment: ahhhh eso me gusta todavia mas.. coleeción o conjunto va :)

Answer (score 3):

## ¿Y si ampliamos un poco el objetivo de Stack Overflow en Español a más aspectos del desarrollo de software y no solo a la programación?

En inglés hay un sitio distinto para los *DBA*, los *SysAdmin*, las cuestiones de seguridad, etc. Si bien hay preguntas que bien podrían caber en StackOverflow hay sitios específicos para ellos (por ejemplo una pregunta sobre cómo automatizar la instalación en un servidor linux mediante scripts podría ir a AskUbuntu o a StackOverflow o a serverfault.

En la respuesta de Pikoh dice:

> ## Misión
>
> Con tu ayuda, queremos crear una recopilación de respuestas
>   detalladas y útiles para cualquier pregunta que pueda surgir en el
>   mundo del desarrollo del software.

que me parece muy correcto, porque es amplio al ***mundo del desarrollo del software***

Sin embargo más adelante dice:

> [...] Conocimiento ilimitado a partir de respuestas de personas reales a ***preguntas de programación***.

Opino que hay que quitar la mención explícita a ***preguntas de programación*** o cambiarla por ***desarrollo de software*** o algo más amplio para que incluya los aspectos de diseño de bases de datos, de interfaces de usuario, de seguridad y todos los demás aspectos que se pueden tener en cuenta en el proceso de desarrollo de software.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en poner desarrollo de software, sobre todo por coherencia en todo el texto..

Answer (score 0):

## Síntesis

Sugiero eliminar

> ## El problema con el conocimiento en español: Menos - Tardío - Pobre.
>
> - En español hay *menos* conocimiento sobre tecnología.
> - El conocimiento aparece con un *retraso*.
> - Lo que está disponible tiende a *no ser exacto o claro*.
>
> ## Solución: Ilimitado - A tiempo - Completo.
>
> - *Conocimiento ilimitado* a partir de respuestas de personas reales a preguntas de programación.
> - Los compañeros desarrolladores te ayudan con el conocimiento *a tiempo*, cuando lo necesitas.
> - Detalles *completos* relacionados con una solución en una respuesta. En ella, el autor explica, en sus propias palabras, cómo ha resuelto
>   el mismo problema.

## Explicación

1. El texto es innecesario
2. Se presta a discusiones estériles

Lo anterior considerando que

1. Stack Overflow en español existe desde hace años,
2. Resulta redundante lo que provoca que el texto sea más extenso de lo necesario.
3. Crea falsas expectativas
4. Carece de sentido lógico hablar primero de la misión, luego de "el problema" y después del "objetivo"

Comment: la vi, por eso borre mi comentario ;) gracias!

Answer (score -1):

## Propuesta a propósito de **Formular y Responder preguntas**

Me parece que el enunciado es insuficiente para atacar eficientemente la ausencia de información pertinente y oportuna en Español. Hay muchísimas buenas preguntas y respuestas en otros sitios de SO, inglés y otros idiomas. Por respeto al tema de créditos de autoría o derechos, ninguno de nosotros (creo) las copiaría y pegaría incluyendo las respuestas pertinentes. **En consecuencia debe abrirse la opción de traducción de modo explícito**. De esta manera uno podría, traducir los materiales que encuentra en sus propias consultas y compartirlos con la comunidad. Hacerlo implicaría adicionar al menú estándar la opción **traducir** o **publicar traducción** (justo al lado del botón **formular pregunta** y hacer aparecer "el artículo" en las listas usuales como si se tratase de una pregunta normal con créditos para sus autores reales y créditos de traductor para quien la ofrece.

Comment: Esto se hace actualmente y se da los creditos correspondientes...

Comment: Como te comenta @gbianchi, es perfectamente aceptado y recomendado que se traduzcan preguntas/respuestas del sitio en inglés. Simplemente puedes crear la pregunta como si fuera una propia y añadir la respuesta en el mismo momento. Si quieres que sea una respuesta colaborativa a la que cualquiera pueda añadir o rectificar contenido, marca la respuesta como "wiki de comunidad".Es importante que añadas el enlace a la pregunta original para dar la atribución necesaria al autor.

Comment: Eso justamente es lo que reduce la cantidad de traducciones disponibles. Algunos somos alérgicos a plantear como propio algo que fue hecho por otros. Si hubiese la opción "traducir" o similar el asunto (colaboración) se estaría planteando sin equívocos, más aún cuando una inmensa parte de los lectores viene y encuentra pregs y resp, y no toman nota de los créditos.

Comment: Creo que no entendiste mi comentario. Por un lado, _es importante que añadas el enlace a la pregunta original para dar la atribución necesaria al autor_, con lo que tu "alergia" a atribuirte algo ajeno queda diluida ya que debes atribuir el contenido al autor. Por otro lado, al marcar la respuesta como "wiki de comunidad" tambien cedes la atribución a la comunidad, y no recibes puntos por ella. Si tu "alergia" se extiende a la pregunta, es sencillo, contacta con algun moderador y pide que la pregunta tambien se marque como wiki. Un saludo.