# Atribución requerida

Tags: discusión, artículo

Todo el contenido contribuido a Stack Overflow u otros sitios de Stack Exchange tiene licencia de [cc-wiki](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.es) (también conocido como [cc-by-sa](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.es)), cuya intención es la de poder ser **compartida y remezclada**. Incluso [proporcionamos todos nuestros datos como un volcado de datos](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), sembrado por nosotros.

Pero nuestra licencia de cc-wiki, si bien es intencionalmente permisiva, requiere atribución.

> Atribución - debe atribuir el trabajo de la manera especificada por el autor o el licenciante (pero no de ninguna manera que sugiera que lo respaldan a usted o al uso que usted hace del trabajo).

Pensé que estaba bastante claro lo que significaba "atribución", pero dada la forma semi-fraudulenta en que está apareciendo el contenido en algunas de las áreas más sembradas de Internet, tal vez no:

<strike>https://stackoverrun.com/</strike> (Nota del traductor - aparentemente, si que atribuyen a Stack Overflow, aunque no de una manera muy clara)

(Puede haber otros; este es sólo uno que conozco)

Así que permítanme aclarar qué entendemos por atribución. Si vuelve a publicar este contenido, le **solicitamos** que:

1. **Visualmente indique que el contenido es de Stack Overflow o de la red de Stack Exchange** de alguna manera. No tiene que ser desagradable; una propaganda discreta de texto está bien.
2. **Enlace directamente a la pregunta original** en el sitio de origen (por ejemplo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
3. **Muestre los nombres de los autores** para cada pregunta y respuesta.
4. **Enlace el nombre de cada autor** directamente a su página de perfil de usuario en el sitio de origen (por ejemplo, http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Por "directamente", me refiero a que cada enlace debe apuntar directamente a nuestro dominio en HTML estándar visible incluso con JavaScript deshabilitado, y no usar un tinyurl o cualquier otra forma de ofuscación o redirección. Además, los enlaces no deben ser [nofollow](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow).

Esto es sobre el espíritu de la justa **atribución**. ¡Atribución al sitio web y, lo que es más importante, a las personas que contribuyeron generosamente con su tiempo para crear ese contenido en primer lugar!

De todos modos, espero que esto aclare cualquier confusión: siéntase libre de volver a mezclar y reutilizar el contenido, siempre y cuando se haga un esfuerzo de buena fe para atribuir el contenido.

---

*Esto es una traducción (mas o menos libre) del [blog de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/), cuyo autor es Jeff Atwood*