# Cambiemos los enlaces sobre las licencias de las contribuciones a páginas traducidas al castellano

Tags: característica-nueva, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Al pie de la página leemos:

> diseño del sitio / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc; contribuciones de usuarios licenciadas bajo [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) con [atribución requerida](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). rev 2018.10.9.31885

Ambos enlaces apuntan a páginas inglesas.

La primera apunta a https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/, cuando la propia Creative Commons ya tiene su versión en castellano en https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/es/

La segunda apunta a un artículo del blog de Stack Overflow, que Pikoh ha traducido en [Atribución requerida](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3695/83).

¿Podrían cambiarse los enlaces o, en su defecto, ponerlos en Transifex para que podamos modificarlos?

Lo que encuentro en traducir.win es [esta cadena](https://traducir.win/string/4633):

> diseño del sitio / logo © $Year$ Stack Exchange Inc; contribuciones de usuarios licenciadas bajo $startCCLink$cc by-sa 3.0$closeLink$ con $startAttributionLink$atribución requerida$closeLink$.

Pero desconozco cómo modificar los enlaces que se le relacionan.

Comment: Enlace a la cadena en traducir.win: https://traducir.win/string/4633 . Totalmente de acuerdo con esta iniciativa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estos links se generan en el código, y como no son markdown no los podemos cambiar nosotros.

Si queres preguntá en meta.SE a ver que te dice alguien del equipo de Q&A

Comment: En ese caso (que era lo que me temía), lo más sencillo será modificar esas cadenas y añadir los enlaces manualmente...

Comment: sip, por eso digo de hablarlo con alguien de Q&A. Estos links son muy distintos a los que usamos en todos lados y seguramente haya una razón para eso.

Comment: Permaneceremos a la espera entonces :)

Comment: yo diría que hagan la pregunta en meta.SE... acá no creo que la vea la gente que puede cambiarlo ;)

Comment: Uy,entendí que la ibas a hacer tu. Ahora la hago

Comment: Ok, [hecho](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316577/346768). Si teneis alguna sugerencia sobre la pregunta decidme por favor

Comment: le sacaría eso de poner los links a mano. No es realmente una opción ya que el string no usa markdown

Comment: ni con rawstring?

Comment: sacto, el html en cadenas traducidas es escapado. El rawstring sirve cuando tenemos markdown (que no es este caso)