# Los textos de la sección "Stack Exchange network" de la parte inferior de la página no están en Transifex

Tags: bug, estado-en-revisión, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Si miramos la parte inferior de la página vemos una serie de bloques "SO en español", "Empresa" y "Stack Exchange network":

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada uno de ellos tiene distintos elementos.

Los elementos del primero, *Stack Overflow en español* y *Empresa*, están disponibles en Transifex - traducir.win. Sin embargo, lo de la última sección, *Stack Exchange network*, no (por ejemplo busqué [`(?i)network$`](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%28%3Fi%29network%24)). Sé que es un índice de sitios, la mayoría de los cuales está en inglés. Sin embargo, creo que sería bueno que los títulos de las secciones sí estuvieran en castellano.

Así pues: ¿podrían añadirse todas estas cadenas para su traducción?

Comment: Relacionado: [Links in the footer in international sites should allow to point to translated pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316577/346768)

Comment: @Pikoh de hecho surgió por la _elevación_ a Meta.SE de [Cambiemos los enlaces sobre las licencias de las contribuciones a páginas traducidas al castellano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3696/83)