# ¿Cómo proponer ampliar el objetivo del sitio para que sea desarrollo de software en general y no solo programación?

Tags: discusión, temática

Quisiera someter a debate el cambio del objetivo del sitio para que no sea solo programación. Ahora al hacer una pregunta lo primero que se lee es:

> ¿Tu pregunta es sobre programación?

En alguna interpretación eso podría dejar afuera cosas que quizás sería bueno que estén incluidas:

1. elección de librerías
2. diseño de base de datos
3. interfaces de usuario
4. seguridad
5. automatización de procesos de apoyo (ej: scripts de instalación, despliegue, mantenimiento de software en servidores)

Mi opinión es que no hace falta ser explícito, basta con cambiar *¿Tu pregunta es sobre programación?* por *¿tu pregunta es sobre desarrollo de software?* o en todo caso *¿tu pregunta es sobre programación o algún otro aspecto del desarrollo de software?*

En otras preguntas de meta ya se tocó el tema (por ejemplo en [Stack overflow internacionales: ilimitado, a tiempo y completo en su idioma nativo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3693/stack-overflow-internacionales-ilimitado-a-tiempo-y-completo-en-su-idioma-nati/3720#comment13431_3720)).

Mi pregunta es cómo iniciar el proceso que puede llevar a este cambio (si es que se cree adecuado).

Comment: El punto 1 ("elección de librerías") no sería un tema válido para el sitio porque se consideraría una pregunta subjetiva y cada respuesta podría ser igualmente válida (entraría dentro de “_¿Cuál es tu ______ favorito?_” como se indica en [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro estoy de acuerdo contigo respecto a la elección (podría quedar búsqueda o nada), lo que me importa es saber si este es el lugar apropiado para debatir la cuestión de fondo (si ampliar para que no sea solo programación), si no lo es ¿dónde sí?. Si es acá ¿cómo?. Si es en esta pregunta, buenísimo. La lista era un ejemplo, yo no pondría ninguna lista o solo algunas de ejemplo en la que estemos todos de acuerdo.

Comment: Posiblemente relacionado: [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/22721)

Comment: Sí, está íntimamente relacionado. Opino igual que se puede definir una ampliación (a los principales temas relacionados con el desarrollo de software) y, si estamos de acuerdo, hilar fino con qué sí y qué no. Pero lo primero es corregir la pregunta restrictiva **¿tu pregunta es de programación?**. Lo que no sé es cómo se toma esa decisión, cuál es el mecanismo, quién lo ejecuta, etc.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer esta bien hacerlo en meta, puedes crear una pregunta con la etiqueta [meta-tag:característica-nueva] y según sean los resultados de la votación podemos pedirle a nuestro nuevo CM que lo haga o a algún moderador ♦, incluso si existe la cadena puede que lo podamos cambiar directamente en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/)

Comment: @KacosPro Esa cadena se tiene que cambiar por un CM o empleado de Stack Overflow. Sigamos con la discusión.

Comment: opino que es buena idea :p espero que lo apliquen, estare atento